# default group policy not found in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008

My old server had some hardware issue so i join new server as secondary domain controller now the old server is completely down, so in new server i got the error 1058 The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \domain\SysVol\domain\Policies{14F3AFF1-A609-4778-AE09-E70D79C6D3E4}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.

that folder is empty please help with this error. thank you.